# how to handle TaskRejectedException in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, completable-future

i am processing kafka messages using spring boot 2.0.2 release and spring kafka 2.1.10 and inserting them into elasticsearch 6.x. I get a batch of 100 messages that i want to insert into ElasticSearch in parallel. moreover i am using manual acknowledge in my  @kafkalistener. I do understand that when my threadPoolTaskExecutor's queue is full i will get TaskRejectedException, I am just catching it, reporting it and throwing it back again.

But the assumption is ack.acknowledge won't get called, and hence the message will be redelivered by kafka. But apparently in message load of 30k messages, i am missing few (~10) messages. I wonder if i am not handling the exceptions correctly that could cause the dropped messages. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my threadPoolTaskExecutor

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class CommonBeanConfig {
    @Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(20);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("KafaSubscriber-Async#");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

Here's the @Async method

```
@Async
    public CompletableFuture<Integer> publishToElasticSearch(String key, EcrAvro avroData) throws Exception {
        logger.warn("ECR avro key=" + key + " - ECR Avro value= " + avroData.toString());
       // check if records exists then update else insert (upsert)
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }
```

Here's my @kafkalistener

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${topic}", containerFactory = "ecrAvroListenerFactory")
public void listen(final Acknowledgment ack, final List<ConsumerRecord<String, EcrAvro>> messages) throws Exception {
    try {
        List<CompletableFuture<Integer>> completableFuturesList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, EcrAvro> kafkaRecord : messages) {
            String key = kafkaRecord.key();
            EcrAvro avroData = kafkaRecord.value();
            completableFuturesList.add(publishToElasticService.publishToElasticSearch(key, avroData));
        }
        CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFuturesList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[completableFuturesList.size()])).join();
        logger.warn("******all threads joined ..!************\n\n");
        ack.acknowledge();
        logger.warn("******acknowledge done..!************\n\n");
    }catch(TaskRejectedException trje){
        logger.warn("******task rejected!************\n\n");
        throw trje;
    }
}
```

My Consumerconfig is shown here as well

```
//Builds the consumer factory, required for @KafkaListener
protected ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> buildConcurrentKafkaListenerFactory(String consumerType) {
    Map<String, Object> properties = initializeCommonConsumerConfig();

    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, environment.getProperty("group.id"));
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer.class);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
    properties.put("schema.registry.url", environment.getProperty("kafka.schema.registry.url"));
    properties.put("specific.avro.reader", "true");

    logger.info("Consumer Factory Properties: " + getPropertyAsString(properties));

    final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConcurrency(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("accountupdate.concurrent.consumer.count")));
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.setConsumerFactory(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Object, Object>(properties));
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL);
    // by default spring kafka is configured to send ack on error, disabling it
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);

    return factory;
}

public Map<String, Object> initializeCommonConsumerConfig() {
    HashMap props = new HashMap();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", environment.getProperty("kafka.bootstrap.servers"));
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", environment.getProperty("enable.auto.commit"));
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", environment.getProperty("session.timeout.ms"));
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", environment.getProperty("auto.offset.reset"));
    props.put("fetch.max.wait.ms", environment.getProperty("fetch.max.wait.ms"));
    props.put("max.partition.fetch.bytes", environment.getProperty("max.partition.fetch.bytes"));
    props.put("max.poll.records", environment.getProperty("max.poll.records"));

    String jaasFile = environment.getProperty("jaasfile");
    System.out.println("Jaas file is " + jaasFile);

    if (jaasFile != null) {
        props.put("security.protocol", environment.getProperty("security.protocol"));
        props.put("sasl.kerberos.service.name", environment.getProperty("sasl.kerberos.service.name"));

        try {
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", this.resourceLoader.getResource(jaasFile).getURI().toString());
        System.out.println("java.security.auth.login.config::" + System.getProperty("java.security.auth.login.config"));
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", environment.getProperty("realm"));
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc", environment.getProperty("kdc"));
        System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", environment.getProperty("krb.debug"));
        System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.principal", environment.getProperty("principal"));
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return props;
}
```

Comment: You should try to log exceptions in `catch` clauses and post results here. Without this information it's hard to say where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "caller runs" rejection policy.

However, Kafka doesn't track message acknowledgments, just an offset in the topic/partition.

If you skip offset 9 and acknowledge offset 10, 9 will never be redelivered.

So, you can't use kafka this way.

Comment: I thought I as a consumer have to acknowledge before Kafka moves the offset. If Kafka is going to move the offset regardless of whether I acknowledge or not then what's the point of acknowledging listener..

Comment: It gives you more control, but you still have to acknowledge in the right order since there is just one offset per partition. It's generally best to let the container handle the acks and use multiple partitions and concurrency in the container instead of an executor.